# Connecting Two LANS

Tags: firewall, local-area-network, router

I have dd-wrt installed on the firewall to my network and I would like to have two external IPs by having two routers and connecting their LANS. I already have two external IP addresses.

This way we can put all the heavy bandwidth on that external IP and when we want to move it over we can transfer it over the LAN.

Idea:

Firewall-0: 192.168.0.1 / 255.255.255.0 (external ip 1)
Firewall-1: 192.168.1.1 / 255.255.255.0 (external ip 2)

Server and heavy bandwidth is at 192.168.0.2-254 and other LAN users of the other external IP are at 192.168.1.2-254. How do I make these two LANs virtually one.

I have tried QoS in the past and that is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is information on the subject via a dual-WAN port device versus two single WAN-port devices.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Dual-WAN_for_simple_round-robin_load_equalization

Comment: ip rule provides load-balancing rules to netfilter

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this in a router and not in ddwrt, but I've done similar, I believe you would have to set up a [VLAN using multiple subnets](http://www.linksysinfo.org/forums/showthread.php?t=39576) and then setup [One to One NAT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/One-to-one_NAT) to assign each public IP to each VLAN interface.